# Android - Passing data from fragment to activity?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-activity

Can you give me an example of passing item in listview from fragment class to activity's listview? appreciate if someone help me thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Android Developer Training site.  It has an implementation of exactly what you ask and is a much better answer:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

```
public static class FragmentA extends ListFragment {

    OnArticleSelectedListener mListener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnArticleSelectedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnArticleSelectedListener");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Append the clicked item's row ID with the content provider Uri
        Uri noteUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ArticleColumns.CONTENT_URI, id);
        // Send the event and Uri to the host activity
        mListener.onArticleSelected(noteUri);
    }

}
```